# Posting a variable to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a welcome controller/view.

On the index.html.erb I have a simple form that takes in one value:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<div>
<%= label_tag(:zip, "Enter Zipcode to search in:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:zip) %>
 </div>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Upon hitting the submit button I'd like to pass the zip variable to another controller called "theaters".  The variable doesnt need to be saved in any kind of model, its just being used to execute an API call in the Theaters controller.

Whats the simplest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: To what action in TheatresController do you want to direct the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "theaters", action: "index"}) do %>
<div>
    <%= label_tag(:zip, "Enter Zipcode to search in:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:zip) %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So this needs a create method in the theaters controller as well?

Comment: In this way you are just passing the value of the text field to the `theaters#index` action.
In the `index` action the `params[:zip]` contains the value of the text field. The `form_tag` method is post by default, so `theaters#index` should be post in the routes.rb.

Comment: So this works if I have a create method that assigns the params to a variable that I output in create.html.erb.  I feel like thats not best practice..?  Can I route it to a different method?

Comment: You have to declare your actions in the routes.rb with and http method like `get`, `post`, an so on. Since `form_tag` method is `post` by default you have to have a post `theaters#index` line in your routes.rb. Obviously you can use `get` method instead but you need to declare your routes as `get` and specifies this in the `form_tag` as well like `form_tag({controller: "theaters", action: "index"}, method: :get) do ...` In this way you can get and read `params[:zip]` in the `TheatersController#index`

Answer (score 0):

Make a route for your method in TheatresController, lets assume your method name is get_zip

```
post '/get_zip' => 'theaters#get_zip', as: "zip"
```

Create your form

```
<%= form_tag(url: zip_path, method: :post) do %>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag(:zip, "Enter Zipcode to search in:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:zip) %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Access it inside your method:

```
def get_zip
  @zip = params[:zip]
  #your logic
end
```

Comment: Hmmm, this gives me a No route matches [POST] "/" routing error

Comment: @Alex did you write this `post '/get_zip' => 'theaters#get_zip', as: "zip"` line in routes.rb

Comment: Yep!  All thats in the routes.rb is the root route (wlecome#index) and that

Comment: @Alex can you post your routes.rb file and also full error that you get by editing your question?

Comment: `root "welcome#index"

  resources :theaters
  post '/get_zip' => 'theaters#get_zip', as: "zip"`

No route matches [POST] "/"
zip_path  POST  /get_zip(.:format)  theaters#get_zip

Comment: @Alex strange this should work. what does rake routes give to you in your terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56902/discussion-between-mandeep-and-alex).